# How do I print a `BdabePublicKey` in Rust?

Tags: rust

How do I print a `BdabePublicKey` in Rust?

```rust
use rabe::schemes::bdabe::*;
use rabe::utils::policy::pest::PolicyLanguage;

fn main() {
   let (_pk , _msk) = setup();
   println!("result: {}", _pk);
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
println!("result: {}", _pk);
  |                   ^^^ `BdabePublicKey` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
[dependencies] 
rabe = "0.2.6" 
rand = "0.7" 
rabe-bn = "0.4.10
```

Comment: `println!("{}", _pk)`

Comment: Please create a [mre] that shows the problem you are having. Note that "minimal" means you should leave out the crates if those are not directly causing the problem; i.e., if you are asking *how to print a variable* they should not be necessary, but if you're asking *how to print a variable of type `rabe::Whatever`* you should provide the code that you tried to use and the error message it gave.

Comment: possibly `println!("{:?}", _pk)`?

Comment: nop vec didnt work

Comment: Actually, [`BdabePublicKey`](https://docs.rs/rabe/0.2.6/rabe/schemes/bdabe/struct.BdabePublicKey.html) doesn't implement Display or Debug.

Comment: It looks like it's meant to be serialized with `serde`

Comment: how serialized with serde?

Comment: I'm not sure, the crate doesn't seem to be well documented.

Comment: The edits to the question have improved it immensely. Now, let me ask a clarifying question: What does it mean to print a variable that cannot be printed? I mean, what do you want this to actually *do*? If I gave you some code, and it printed `Meow meow meow meow meow meow`, how would you know whether that was the right thing or not?

Comment: well it suppose to be a generated key () , it should be printed, https://docs.rs/rabe/0.2.6/rabe/schemes/bdabe/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can print out some of its fields:

```
fn print_key(key: BdabePublicKey) {
    println!("_g1: {} _g2: ? _p1: {} _p2: ? _e_gg_y: {}", key._g1, key._p1, key._e_gg_y);
}
```

Comment: thread 'main' has overflowed its stack
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\hello.exe` (exit code: 0xc00000fd, STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW)

Answer (score 0):

You can try serialising it into json and printing that also:

```rust
fn print_key(key: &BdabePublicKey) {
    let json = serde_json::to_string(key).unwrap();
    println!("{}", json);
}
```

in `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
serde_json = "1.0"
```

Comment: not what i expected, but yeah it print !! thx